# getting this error Uncaught TypeError: product.color?.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

## I'm getting an error called "Uncaught TypeError: product.color?.map is not a function" i'm getting this error when i try to map the color of product is single product page

```
<Filter>
   <FilterTitle>Color</FilterTitle>
      {product.color?.map((c)=>(
      <FilterColor color={c} key={c} />
   ))}
</Filter>
```

[my console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J4F8.png)

## I fetching product data form here

```
const Product = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const getProduct = async () => {
        try {
          const res = await publicRequest.get("/products/find/" + id);
          setProduct(res.data.product);
        //   console.log(res);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
      };
      getProduct();
    }, [id]);
```

## This is the data i received

[the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGds7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The effect is going to be called after the component is initially rendered, therefore in the first render, the `product.color` is undefined. And it seems that `color` is a string, not an array therefore you do not need to use `map`, just display the result.

You can put a conditional to only render when you get the result from the API:

```
<Filter>
   {product.color !== undefined &&
     <FilterTitle>Color</FilterTitle>
     <FilterColor color={product.color} key={product.color} />
   }
</Filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you provided, a product.color is a single object so, you can't use the map in a single object.

```
<Filter>
   <FilterTitle>Color</FilterTitle>
   <FilterColor color={product[1].color} /> // pass the product[0].color value
</Filter>
```

If you want to map then you have to map the product which has multiple objects

```
 <Filter>
  <FilterTitle>Color</FilterTitle>
  {product.map((product, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <FilterColor color={product.color} />
      <div>Price: {product.price}</div>
      <div>Size: {product.size}</div>
      {/* add more product details here as needed */}
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</Filter>
```